# link functions with mismatching signature

Tags: gcc, linker, g++, elf

I'm playing around with **gcc** and **g++** compiler and trying to compile some C code within those, my purpose is to see how the compiler / linker enforces that when linking a model with some function declaration to a model with that implementation of that function, the correct function are linked ( in terms of parameters passed and values returned )

for example let's take a look at this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int foo(int b, int c);

int main()
{
 int f = foo(5, 8);

 printf("%d",f);
}
```

after compilation within my symbol table I'd have a symbol for foo, but within the elf file format there is not place that describes the arguments taken and the function signature, ( `int(int,int)` ), so basically if I write some other code such as this:

```
char foo(int a, int b, int c)
{

 return (char) ( a + b + c );

}
```

compile that model it'll also have some symbol called foo, what if I link these models together, what's gonna happen? I have never thought of this, and how would a compiler overcome this weakness... I know that within g++ the compiler generates some prefix for every symbol regarding to it's namespace, but does it also take in mind the signature? If anyone has ever encountered this it would be great if he could shed some light upon this problem

Comment: You have tagged with C yet ask about C++. They are different languages and the answer may be different depending on which language you are really asking about. Please clarify.

Comment: It's not clear. Nowhere do you mention "compiling c within g++". You do realise that C++ code can look like C code but is not the same thing at all? So "compiling C within g++" itself is unclear - if you compile the code as shown in g++ then it is by definition C++ code not C code. To compile C code with g++ requires extra syntax. If you don't understand what that means then suggest you research a bit. This point is very important for your question actually and needs to be made clear.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Your question is particularily very different regarding those languages. So pick **one** of them!

Comment: I agree with you, maybe title should be edited yet purposely this was not tagged under C++ @Olaf

Comment: Then the answer is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved [with name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

> In compiler construction, name mangling (also called name decoration)
>   is a technique used to solve various problems caused by the need to
>   resolve unique names for programming entities in many modern
>   programming languages.
>
> It provides a way of encoding additional information in the name of a
>   function, structure, class or another datatype in order to pass more
>   semantic information from the compilers to linkers.
>
> The need arises where the language allows different entities to be
>   named with the same identifier as long as they occupy a different
>   namespace (where a namespace is typically defined by a module, class,
>   or explicit namespace directive) or have different signatures (such as
>   function overloading).

Note [the simple example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Simple_example):

> Consider the following two definitions of f() in a C++ program:
>
> ```
> int  f (void) { return 1; }
> int  f (int)  { return 0; }
> void g (void) { int i = f(), j = f(0); }
> ```
>
> These are distinct functions, with no relation to each other apart
>   from the name. If they were natively translated into C with no
>   changes, the result would be an error — C does not permit two
>   functions with the same name. The C++ compiler therefore will encode
>   the type information in the symbol name, the result being something
>   resembling:
>
> ```
> int  __f_v (void) { return 1; }
> int  __f_i (int)  { return 0; }
> void __g_v (void) { int i = __f_v(), j = __f_i(0); }
> ```
>
> Notice that g() is mangled even though there is no conflict; name
>   mangling applies to all symbols.

Comment: Ahh thank you very much yet I found the answer to my question my self :)

Comment: @DrPrItay: It was incomplete when you had C and C++ in mind and it is wrong now as you have clarified you ask about C. If you don't understand the difference, you should start from scratch.

Comment: If this answer does answer your question, your question apparently is about C++ only.

Comment: So why then intentionally using the wrong tag, violating site-rules?

Comment: as said earlier, it was a mistake and I've edited my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I've kept exploring and testing it on my own and I came up with a solution which quietly amazed my mind,

so I wrote the following code and compiled it on a gcc compiler

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int foo(int a, char b);

int main()
{
 int g = foo(5, 6);
 printf("%d", g);
 return 0;
}
```

**foo.c**

```
typedef struct{
 int a;
 int b;
 char c;
 char d;

} mystruct;

mystruct foo(int a, int b)
{
 mystruct myl;

 my.a = a;
 my.b = a + 1;
 my.c = (char) b;
 my.d = (char b + 1;

 return my1;
}
```

now I compiled `foo.c` to `foo.o` with **gcc** firstly and checked the symbol table using 
`readelf` and I had some entry called `foo`

also after that I compiled `main.c` to `main.o` checked the symbol table and it also had some entry called `foo`, I linked those two together and surprisingly it worked, I ran `main.o` and obviously encountered some segmentation fault, which makes sense as the actual implementation of `foo` as implemented in `foo.o` probably expects three parameters (first one should be struct adders), a parameter which isn't passed in `main.o` under it's definition to `foo` then the actual implementation accesses some memory that doesn't belong to it from the stack frame of `main`, then tries accessing addresses that it thought it got, and ends up with segmentation fault, that's fine,

now I compiled both models again with **g++** and not **gcc** and what came up was amazing.. I found out that the symbol entry under `foo.o` was `_Z3fooii` and under `main.o` it was `_Z3fooic`, now my guess is that the `ii` suffix means `int int` and `ic` suffix means `int char` which probably refers to the parameters that should be passed to function hence allowing the compiler to know some function deceleration gets the actual implementation. so I changed my `foo` declaration in `main.c` to

```
extern int foo(int a, int b);
```

re-compiled and this time got the symbol `_Z3fooii`, I linked both models again and amazingly this time it worked, I tried running it and again encountered segmentation fault, which again also makes sense as the compiler wont always even authorize correct return values.. anyways what was my original thought - that **g++** includes function signature within symbol name and thus enforces the linker to give function implementation get correct parameters to correct function declaration

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behaviour. It is no way correct!

Comment: Invoking UB is the purpose? I hopy you never work in the same project team as I do (and I never have to rely on code you wrote).

Comment: OT: in C11 there is a way to overload functions without torturing the compiler :) take a look to [_Generic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34733174/1606345)